# ROR + Ransack: Rendering selected search parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ransack

I am trying to render the strings of the search parameters passed to the ransack search.

However, i can't figure a way of detecting if a specific attribute was included in the search. Below code works but will not hide the button if the param is empty.

**articles/browse.html.erb**

```
  <% if params[:q].present? == true %>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg"><%= params[:q][:title_cont] %></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg"><%= params[:q][:categories_name_cont] %></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg"><%= params[:q][:user_name_cont] %></button>
  <% end %>
```

I tried using below condition but it give this error: `undefined method [] for nil:NilClass`

```
 <% if params[:q][:title_cont].present? == true %>
```

**Articles controller**

```
  def browse
    @q = Article.ransack(params[:q])
    @articles = @q.result.includes(:categories, :users)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by changing `<% if params[:q][:title_cont].present? == true %>`

to `<% if @q.title_cont.present? == true %>`

browse.html.erb

```
    <% if @q.title_cont.present? == true %>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg"><%= params[:q][:title_cont] %></button>
    <% end %>
    <% if @q.categories_name_cont.present? == true %>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg"><%= params[:q][:categories_name_cont] %></button>
    <% end %>
    <% if @q.user_name_cont.present? == true %>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg"><%= params[:q][:user_name_cont] %></button>
    <% end %>
```